# FLVPlayback keeps playing on page change

Tags: flash, actionscript-3, flvplayback

I have a as3 project, a magazine like project.
I have like 10 pages, and some of those pages, has a FLVPlayback component to stream flv videoes.
I have one problem, and it goes like this:

When i enter a frame, with a FLVPlayback component and start playing the video, everything works fine. But when i then switch to another page, the video file keeps playing in the background.

Is this a common problem ?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

Yes, FLVPlayback component keeps playing until you call `stop()`. It's not enough to remove it from the display list.

Comment: At the moment, im asking on behalf of the action script man, Ill forward the answer to him, and come back if it solve his problem :)

Comment: You have to actively call stop() on the FLVPlayback component. For example you can do that in an Event.REMOVED_FROM_STAGE listener. If you just remove it from the displaylist, it will continue playling, like @DanielB said. It will stop eventually, when the GC collects it, but you never can tell when this will happen.